# Callback with Stripe and Paymentsheet

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am implementing the Paymentsheet method of Stripe in my application, but i can't find a callback or something else to know if the payment has been confirmed or there have been problems.

Is this information available with Paymentsheet? If not, how can i pay using stripe sdk and receive a callback of the call

Answer (score 1):

> I tried with try and catch only because using webhook it tooks some time for our mobile UI. Though, Webhook is the best option. Whatever I did here is some time of patch.

```
    Future<void> _presentPaymentSheet(
      BuildContext context, String? clientSecret) async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
  
      // ==> Here, I assume payment success
      state = NetworkState.success;
      
    } on Exception catch (stripeException) {
      if (stripeException is StripeException) {
        state = NetworkState.error;
        if (stripeException.error.code == FailureCode.Canceled) {
          context.showSnackBar(AppStrings.errorFromStripe +
              (stripeException.error.localizedMessage ?? ''));
          context.pop();
        } else {
          debugLog('Error7: $stripeException');
          context.showSnackBar(AppStrings.errorFromStripe +
              (stripeException.error.localizedMessage ?? ''));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem is that I don't simply need to know if the payment is completed, but also the informations related that i can see from the web dashboard, like fees, total payed, ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Stripe webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to be notified when the payment succeeds. More specifically you should listen to the `payment_intent.succeeded` event. You can learn more about this in [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet#ios-post-payment).